# On average, how often do university faculty file patents?

Tags: university, faculty, professor

I'm helping a small college set up their Engineering program, and the administrator I'm working with asked a perfectly valid question: how often will they have to deal with this?  How much budget would they have to allocate to it each year?

So, my question to all of you is the first one, with a bit of modification:

How many patents are likely to be filed by 10 Engineering faculty over a span of 10 years?

Answer (score 1):

Your title says "university" but your question mentions small college. I'd expect that there is a major difference in the number of patents generated by a research university with graduate programs and a small college with an undergraduate only engineering department. I used [The Lens](https://www.lens.org/lens/search/patent/structured) to do a search for [patents applied for by Union College](https://www.lens.org/lens/search/patent/list?p=0&n=10&s=date_published&d=%2B&f=false&e=false&l=en&authorField=author&dateFilterField=publishedDate&orderBy=%2Bdate_published&presentation=false&preview=true&stemmed=true&useAuthorId=false&applicant.must=UNION%20COLLEGE) which is a small liberal arts college with an engineering department. There were 15 publications in total of which 12 were applications. Three were granted patents and only four are pending. Some of those might even come from science faculty. A similar search for Swarthmore College yield no hits at all. It may be that Swarthmore uses some other name for its applications, but I couldn't figure it out. A similar search could be done for other comparable colleges to the one you are advising and statistics compiled. You could use the link I provided and change the applicant field.

Bottom line is for a small college with only undergraduate education I'd expect very few if any patents filed each year. The mission of such colleges is education first and they do relatively little research. A major research university like Stanford or MIT would be a completely different situation.

Comment: That's a very good point, and that's very helpful.  I believe I will follow your advice to generate some statistics.

Comment: As an update, it appears that the search may be more complicated than it first seemed; depending on how the college in question handles patents, the college's name may not appear as one of the applicants or as one of the owners.  I think that while this method will still be helpful to gather some data, it won't be the complete answer I was hoping it would be.

Comment: @Will Most universities I'm aware of have a single assignee for patents they pay for. It might not be true for all, but it hardly matters since you only need to find some comparable colleges to get a reasonable estimate. By the way, there isn't an answer since the patent productivity is an individual thing. Robert Langer has over a thousand patents. Other MIT professors have none.

Comment: @Will I should mention that the college need not pursue a patent on the professor’s invention. Usually the school will do so if it believes there is licensing potential and thus a positive return on investment.